# when loading a new database in datatool only the first key works

Tags: datatool, key-value

I try to load a .csv into my .tex using datatool, but it uses only the first given key and I just don't get why.

first lines of my example foobar.csv:

```
1;a;ax
2;b;be
2;c;ck
3;d;do
```

(at the end the last column will be filled with picture.jpg, that will be loaded into a tkizpicture and it works fine if I take only the last column. The same applies for the other columns they will have a special action that works fine if I take only that one column.)

mwe:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={1,2,3}]{foobar}{foobar.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLdisplaydb{foobar}
\end{document}
```

it isn't giving an error, as I don't use the key in this example, but it isn't printing the keys 2 and 3, but only 1. It is printing the three columns perfectly, but not the keys.
If I use the key in a more complex example I get the error:

> foobar.tex:51: Package data tool Error: Can't assign \Title : there is no key '2' in data base 'foobar'.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is quite easy, just had to add

```
\DTLsetseparator{;}
```

before

```
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={1,2,3}]{foobar}{foobar.csv}
```

as the separator seemed to be the problem.